# How to get actual client IP instead of docker IP?

Tags: javascript, docker, express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

In my express app, I am reading the ip like this: 
`const ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress;`
I returned the ip when someone hit / from the app.

and This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://api:3000; #port where you are serving your express app.

  }
}
```

But, when I run the app in localhost, I am getting dockerIp (172.31.0.1) instead of actual client ip. how can I get that?

Comment: When you're running the app locally do you still have `nginx` in front of it and making the request through nginx rather than directly to the app? Because `X-Forwarded-For` is set by proxies (like nginx) not the browser.

Comment: I think, I am making the request through nginx.
it is a straightforward simple express app: 
https://github.com/ashiqdev/exp-nginx-docker

Comment: Post the exact URL you're accessing.

Comment: `localhost`
just localhost

Comment: could that help: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ips ?

Comment: Did you deploy the whole stack or just the app? Make sure you're hitting the correct nginx instance: check the docker logs for the nginx instance.

Comment: there is only two service inside docker-compose file, one is nginx and another is api.
and I am using http://api:3000; as proxy-pass